# Does this box in the movie 妖猫传 (Legend of the Demon Cat) say 鳳栖樓 on its lid and 私人必死 inside, and what do they mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, character-identification

I'm watching the movie [妖猫传](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A6%96%E7%8C%AB%E4%BC%A0/19364652) (yāomāo zhuàn) = Legend of the Demon Cat.  About 10 minutes into the movie, a man secretly enters a room named 御宬 (yùchéng) = "imperial storage" (I think) and searches for a hidden box.  He reaches for the box:

> [image]

I think this says something like:

> 鳳栖樓

meaning "pheonix perch building" (using a mix of traditional and simplified characters).  He opens the box, and takes out a special key:

[image]

It looks like it says something like:

- [私人](http://dict.cn/%E7%A7%81%E4%BA%BA) = private
- [必死](http://dict.cn/%E5%BF%85%E6%AD%BB) = "die the death"

I don't know what this means.  When he uses the key, he's almost killed by a trap.

I want to check I've correctly transcribed these two items, and ask what they mean.  The first simply seems to be simply a fancy name of the room where the key is used.

**Question**: Does this box say 鳳栖樓 on its lid and 私人必死 inside, and what do they mean?

Comment: It is 私入(ru4, enter), not 私人.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never saw the movie.

鳳栖樓 should be the name of the building. You are mentioning there is a key in the box, so it is probably the building where the key is for.

As the note inside the box, you got one character wrong. It is "私入必死", where 入(ru4) means "enter".

Here, 私 means "without permission". So the whole phrase is saying the "(you) will definitely die if enter without permission"

入 and 人 look alike, but are two totally different characters.